# Close form window after submission of Form which also includes a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a web application where I have a create email window pop up where the user fills in the email details like subject, body etc. After the form is submitted I would like the window to close.
I got it working using jquery and ajax code:

```
 $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var BoldText = document.getElementById("DivDescription").innerHTML;
        SendMessageurl = '@Url.Action("CreateMail", "Communication")';
        $(".overlay").show();
        var mysave = $('#DivDescription').html();
        var des = $('#Description').text(mysave);
        var formdata = $("#form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: SendMessageurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            success: function (result) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.close();
                },2000);               
            }
        });
    });
```

Where after 2 seconds the window would close.
Now I want to add an attachment with an email. The following code does that but doesn't close the window:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var BoldText = document.getElementById("DivDescription").innerHTML;
    SendMessageurl = '@Url.Action("CreateMail", "Communication")';
    $(".overlay").show();
    var mysave = $('#DivDescription').html();
    var des = $('#Description').text(mysave);
    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    var totalFiles = document.getElementById("inputUpload").files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = document.getElementById("inputUpload").files[i];
            formdata.append("inputUpload", file);
        };

    $.ajax({
        url: SendMessageurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.close();
            },2000);               
        }
    });
});
```

After debugging, I found that after form's submitted it wouldn't enter the success block.Not sure why. 
This is my html code:

```html
     <i class="fa fa-icon-paperclip"><input type="file" class="filestyle" id="inputUpload" style="opacity:0;" multiple /></i>
<input class="contact2-form-btn" type="submit" value="Send" id="emailsubmit" style="cursor:pointer" />
```

Please Help!!!

Thanks in advance.

**Update** :
I resolved this issue by changing the dataType from "json" to "text". THANKS

Comment: Are you sure the request is succeeding? Try adding an error handler to your AJAX call to see if there's an error occurring.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I tested it out again using dataType:'text' and now it works. Since my datatype was json it was giving a problem...